# Correct way to define parity of two parafermions

Tags: conventions, fermions, parity, spin-statistics

I am checking the literature on [parafermions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parastatistics) and it seems that people define the parity of two parafermions to be $\gamma_{a}^{-1}\gamma_{b}$. Is this definition always valid? How does one come up with this definition?

Comment: The "parity" is the generator of the $\mathbb{Z}_N$ symmetry for parafermions, and in recent literature on realizing parafermions on the edge of fractional quantum Hall states, this quantity has physical meaning (i.e. fractional charge) and one can show they are conserved.

Comment: @MengCheng : thanks; can I ask you another question- In http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0113, Wen talks about projective non-abelian anyons. In http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3379, do you know how it has been made sure that they are working with the projective non-abelian anyons because it seems they treat the anyons just as the non-abelian anyons instead of ones that are said to obey projective non-abelian statistics. It seems that they just start with non-abelian anyons, right ?

Comment: Projective statistics means that the overall phase of the braiding is not well-defined, but the relative phase between different fusion channels is still well-defined. In most recent research on Majorana zero modes and parafermion zero modes, only the latter is used since it is known for quite a while (in the context of Majorana zero modes) that the overall phase is not fixed.

Comment: @MengCheng: thanks. So, in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1838.pdf, there are properties of twists which classify them into $\sigma_{+}$ and $\sigma_{-}$ which obey the fusion rules but cannot be called as anyons. I am unable to identify the connection between the extrinsic anyons of Wen and Bombin's twists. Can Bombin's twists which are of two types, under some projection, be used as non-abelian anyons ? Is that what is implied by your statement. I am missing something. It will be very helpful if you could share your insight on this.

Comment: Bombin's is a special case of Wen's model($N=2$), so I'm not sure what kind of connection you were looking for. The two types of dislocations are topologically distinct, and each of them behaves like Ising anyons $\sigma$ except that the overall phase when you braid a $\sigma_+$ with $\sigma_+$ is not well-defined. The fact that they are distinct can be measured by a Wilson loop of $\psi$ anyon around them: for $\sigma_+$ you should get $1$ and $\sigma_-$ it is $-1$.

Comment: Yes, I was referring only to special case $N=2$. I was confused because Wen said that those 'anyons' could be used for TQC while Bombin said that they are not really anyons. I understand your point now that Bombin and Wen are referring to the same extrinsic anyon due to dislocation- thanks for confirming that. As Bombin says, one cannot 'directly compare' braiding $\psi$ around $\sigma_{+}$ with braiding $\psi$ around trivial charge $1$; So, does that mean that one cannot compare $\sigma_{+}$ and trivial charge by braiding $\psi$ around them ? this doesn't affect anything ?

Comment: Bombin is right that one cannot 'directly compare' braiding $\psi$ around $\sigma_+$ with braiding $\psi$ around trivial charge, essentially because $\sigma_+$ and trivial charge lives in different "defect" sectors. However, my point is that you can use braiding of $\psi$ around $\sigma_\pm$ to tell the difference between $\sigma_+$ and $\sigma_-$, which are in the same "defect" sector.

Comment: It is simpler to tell whether there is a $\sigma_\pm$ or not: it is a dislocation, so just by looking at how things are spatially translated is enough to locate the position. If you really want to understand the precise meaning of the projective braiding (i.e. which ones are meaningful), I suggest you look at my paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.4540.pdf, especially Sec. V and VI. Sec. VI C discussed the gauge transformations of the defect R symbols, from which one can determine which braiding processes are meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26259/discussion-between-user56199-and-meng-cheng).

Comment: @MengCheng:- Hi Meng Cheng, do you know if there is a general result for F and R matrices for parafermions ? I can derive it for small N but it would be nice to know if there is a reference for general result

Comment: The general case of $\mathbb{Z}_N$ parafermion for odd $N$ is in my paper, see the example section (section X. E).

Comment: Thanks!! I see the solutions for G-crossed braiding- I am do not see how one could use that as a general solution but I will try to read your paper more carefully to find that out. But what does the exponent $p$ in $Z^{p}_{N}$ stand for ? - Does it relate to taking $p$ combinations of anyons together ?

Comment: That's just a label for different anyon models with $Z_N$ fusion rules. For $N$ odd, the $F$ symbols of the anyons are trivial and the $R$ symbols are given by $R^{ab}=e^{2\pi ipab/N}$. We have given a complete characterization of "parafermion" type defects in this kind of anyon model, including all the defect $F$ and $R$ symbols, basically by solving all consistency equations.

Comment: Thanks. It will be great to know what are the $F$ and $R$ symbols of $C_{G}$ if you have an intuitive explanation- basically why are they different or what is $C_{G}$. Else, I have this paper on my reading list anyways as it seems to explain a lot of nice concepts- will try to understand carefully then. Thanks again!

Comment: Meng Cheng- if $p$ is just a label, why does it appear in the solution for F and R matrices - are there multiple solutions to F and R matrices for $Z_{N}$ anyons and all those solutions are being called as different anyon models ? Thanks. So, in general, I can choose any p, right ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_N$ here just means fusion rules. There can be different anyon models with the same fusion rules. For example, if $N=3$, $\mathbb{Z}_N^{(2)}$ is $\mathrm{SU}(3)_1$ theory and $\mathbb{Z}_N^{(1)}$ is the conjugate. They are different topological phases. For each one, you can study the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ defects and solve for $F$ and $R$ of defects. What $p$ you choose of course depends on how the parafermions are realized, since that's the "parent" state where the defects live.